# How to get ROE%20 from %s%20?

Tags: python

There is a way to get it .

```
>>> name="ROE"
>>> s1='%s'
>>> s2=s1 %name +'%20'
>>> s2
'ROE%20'
```

Can i change the following way to get it?

```
>>> name="ROE"
>>> s1='%s%20'
>>> s2=s1 %name
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: incomplete format
```

I want to keep `%20` in the s1 string and substitute `%s` with `ROE` ,is there another way to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution using the newer and recommended [`str.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
s1 = "{0}%20"
s2 = s1.format(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to escape the percent sign by doubling it.

```
>>> "%s%%20" % "ROE"
'ROE%20'
```